# C# List items got overwritten by last added item

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with all properties of each item in a List<ButtonTemplateModel> get values of the last added item. Does anyone know why?

```js
    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(EpisodeVM EpisodeBtnConfig)
    {
      Dictionary<string,string> stageType = Helpers.EpisodeCommandButtonSettings.stageType;
      Dictionary<string, string> actionBtnClass = Helpers.EpisodeCommandButtonSettings.actionBtnColor;
      List<ButtonTemplateModel> cmdButtonVMList = new();
      string rawID;
      
      if (EpisodeBtnConfig.EpisodeID > 0)
      {
        rawID = EpisodeBtnConfig.PINFK;
        EpisodeBtnConfig.PINFK = rawID.Substring(rawID.Length - 4, 4);
      }

      /* iterate 8 stage types */
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in stageType)
      {
        ButtonTemplateModel  cmdBtnTemplateVM = new()
        {
          ActionVM = EpisodeBtnConfig.ActionButtonVM,
          Title = entry.Value,
          Stage = entry.Key,
          TextNode = entry.Key,
          ActionBtnCssClass = actionBtnClass[entry.Key],
          ShowThisButton = true,
          DisableThisButton = false
        };

        switch (cmdBtnTemplateVM.Stage)
        {
          case "PeopleList":
            cmdBtnTemplateVM.TextNode = "Back to People List";
            if (EpisodeBtnConfig.ActionButtonVM.HostingPage == "Question")
            {
              cmdBtnTemplateVM.ActionVM.ControllerName = "PeopleList";
              cmdBtnTemplateVM.ActionVM.ActionName = "Index";
              cmdBtnTemplateVM.ActionVM.PeopleListID = string.Empty;
              cmdBtnTemplateVM.ActionVM.EpisodeID = -1;
            }
            else
              cmdBtnTemplateVM.ShowThisButton = false;
            break;

          case "Full":
            cmdBtnTemplateVM.TextNode = "IRF-PAI";
            break;

          case "Followup":
            cmdBtnTemplateVM.TextNode = "Follow Up";
            break;
        }

        if (EpisodeBtnConfig.ActionButtonVM.EpisodeID == -1 && (cmdBtnTemplateVM.Stage != "PeopleList" && cmdBtnTemplateVM.Stage != "Base"))
          cmdBtnTemplateVM.DisableThisButton = true;

        if (EpisodeBtnConfig.ActionButtonVM.EpisodeID != -1 && cmdBtnTemplateVM.Stage != "New")
          cmdBtnTemplateVM.Title = cmdBtnTemplateVM.Title.Replace("Create new", "Edit existing");

        cmdButtonVMList.Add(cmdBtnTemplateVM);
      }

      string viewName = "StageCommandBtn";
      return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View(viewName, cmdButtonVMList));
```

Comment: Is EpisodeBtnConfig.ActionButtonVM being passed as a reference type? Maybe have to create a new clone

Comment: just because its prettier move that definition outside of the foreach loop: ButtonTemplateModel  cmdBtnTemplateVM;

Comment: Not sure why but I would bet you are adding 8 times the same instance. You could check with an 'if commandbuttonVMList.Contains(commandButtonTrmplateVM) throw new Exception();' Sorry for not formatting. I am on my smartphone.

Comment: Each cmBtnTemplateVM is instantiated at the beginning of each iteration and gets different properties from the iterated KeyValuePair.  So defining it outside the foreach loop doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Can you show the definition of that ButtonTemplateModel?

Comment: Instantiating the button outside the loop and then just updating the properties, is the usual source of these kinds of errors. But you do that correctly here.